# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.' when assigning a class to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my profile.html.erb file I get a syntax error anytime I try to assign a class or id to erb. Below is an example:

```
<p>"<%= current_user.current_program.name, :id => 'progress' %>" Progress</p>
```

This gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError in Users#profile

Showing /.../app/views/users/profile.html.erb where line #13 raised:

/Users/.../app/views/users/profile.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...er.current_program.name, :id => 'progress' );@output_buffer....
...                               ^
```

I can't figure out what the syntax error is. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: FYI: Erb doesn't know about 'classes' or 'id'. All it knows is that `<% … %>` runs Ruby code and `<%= … %>` runs Ruby code, calls `to_s` on the result and sticks the string in that spot. You have to use Rails helpers if you want to generate HTML-aware content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reproduce and simplify your problem in a standalone Ruby like so:

```
require 'erb'
ERB.new("<p><%= name, :a => 'b' %></p>").run
```

Producing the error:

```
SyntaxError: (erb):1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
..."; _erbout.concat(( name, :a => 'b' ).to_s); _erbout.concat ...
...                               ^
    from /Users/phrogz/.../ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
    from /Users/phrogz/.../ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
    from /Users/phrogz/.../ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:820:in `run'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/phrogz/.../bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Even more simply, taking ERB out of the mix:

```
a, :b=>'c'
#=> SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
```

What you have just isn't valid Ruby code. What were you trying to do there? Pass the `:id => 'progress'` hash as a parameter to the `.name` method? If so, then drop the comma, and (optionally) include parentheses for clarity:

```erb
<p>"<%= current_user.current_program.name( :id=>'progress' ) %>" Progress</p>
```

*And if you're using Ruby 1.9+, you can use the simpler Hash-with-symbol-keys syntax:*

```erb
<p>"<%= current_user.current_program.name( id:'progress' ) %>" Progress</p>
```

However, it seems unlikely to me that the `name` method takes such a hash, so I ask again: what are you really trying to accomplish? What does the `name` method return, and what HTML output do you want?

---

Taking a guess, maybe you wanted the text returned by `.name` to be wrapped in `<span id="progress">`? If so, you must do so like:

```erb
<p>"<span id="progress"><%= current_user.current_program.name%></span>" Progress</p>
```

Or perhaps using [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag):

```erb
<p><%= content_tag("span", current_user.current_program.name, id:'progress') %> Progress</p>
```

In Haml this would be:

```haml
%p
  %span#progress= current_user.current_program.name
  Progress
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. I was trying to assign a class to the word that was generated by current_user.current_program.name, and thought I could just assign it with :id => 'progress'. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: FWIW I strongly recommend [Haml](http://haml.info) over Erb. It's less typing, and more cleanly organized.

Comment: So, for assigning a class you'd want `class:…` instead of `id:…`, right?

Comment: yeah, exactly. I meant id. It might be time for a break.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you remove the comma it will work (is `current_user.current_program.name` a method that takes a hash as a parameter?)